# NSLocalized string returns key instead of value

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslocalizedstring

Our app contains two Localizable files in `en.lproj` and in `nl.lproj`. The files are copied to the product. ([Check the IPA](http://film.alessandrovermeulen.me/BINK%20Glaser.ipa).) When requesting the localized string with `NSLocalizedString(@"input_dialog_title", nil)` we get the key as a result. The Localizable file is visible in the XCode project tree and has the two localized versions.

**Update:** There is no old Localizable.strings file in the root of the IPA. I cleaned and rebuild the project. I even tried restarting XCode.

**Update2:** The locale is en_US. I tested both `nl` and `en` through the -AppleLanguages (xx) parameter.

Any ideas as to why this happens?

The contents of the string files are as follows. For the English version:

```
/* 
  Localizable.strings
  BINK Glaser

  Created by Alessandro Vermeulen on 31-07-13.
  Copyright (c) 2013 Alessandro Vermeulen. All rights reserved.
 */

"input_dialog_title" = "New Value";
```

And for the Dutch version:

```
/* 
  Localizable.strings
  BINK Glaser

  Created by Alessandro Vermeulen on 31-07-13.
  Copyright (c) 2013 Alessandro Vermeulen. All rights reserved.
*/

"input_dialog_title" = "Nieuwe waarde";
```

Comment: Does the IPA contain an old (empty) Localizable.strings file in the root directory? Usually this kind of thing can go back when you start from a non-localized file and localize it. The old file hangs around in the build products and .app until you do a clean build and remove it from the simulator/device.

Comment: maybe a wrong localization is set, so the framework search for a nonexistent strings file.

Comment: @MikeWeller There is no old Localizable.strings file in the root or anywhere else.

Comment: @MrQ.C. The locale for the english version is "en_US" so that should be okay, right?

Comment: are those Localizable.strings files added to the target?

Comment: @verbumdei: What do you mean exactly? They are in the IPA and the target app/executable has the following rule listed: "Process: Localization string files; Using: CopyStringsFile".

Comment: I was facing the same issue few days ago, and i solved it by renaming the "super" `.strings` file. Also make sure the `Localizable.strings` files are added to the target as @verbumdei said before.